# Optimal way to crop images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

The problem is simple and common. I have a few boxes with images and text and I want all of them to have the same size regardless of picture dimension and ofcourse to behave nicely on responsive. How can I make it better that I already did? On my local machine the javascript is working but for reasons I can't understand , here is not. The javascript code is checking if a picture is in portrait mode and adds another class . Thanks .

```js
$(document).ready( function() {

function getImgDim(pic) {
    var image = new Image(),
          dim = [];
    image.src = $(pic).attr("src");
    dim = [image.naturalWidth , image.naturalHeight];
    return dim;
  };
  
  function getContDim(pic) {
    return $(pic).parent().width();
  };
  
  function portrait (picture) {
    
    $(picture).each(function() {
      var dim = getImgDim(this);
      // console.log(dim);
      if( dim[0] < dim[1] || dim[0] < getContDim(this)) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('u-center-landscape'); 
        $(this).parent().addClass('u-center-portrait');
      }
    });
  };
  
  portrait('.js-box');
  
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.boxes {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px; 
}
  .boxes:after, .boxes:before {
    display: table;
    content: "";
  }
  .boxes:after {
    clear: both; 
  }

  .boxes figure {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px; 
  }

  .boxes__content {
    cursor: pointer; 
  }

    .boxes__content:hover {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.25);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.25);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.25);
      border-radius: 10px; 
    }
      .boxes__content:hover .u-center-portrait img {
        width: 110%;
        transition: width 0.3s ease; 
      }

      .boxes__content:hover .u-center-landscape img {
        height: 110%;
        transition: height 0.3s ease;
      }

  .boxes figcaption {
    line-height: 60px; 
  }
  .boxes__title {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333; 
  }
  .boxes__img {
    height: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; 
  }

.u-center-landscape img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.u-center-portrait img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="boxes">
        
        <figure>
          <div class="boxes__content">
            <div class="boxes__img u-center-landscape">
              <img class="js-box" src="http://lorempixel.com/700/500/" alt="">
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxes__title">Mitteilungen</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <div class="boxes__content">
            <div class="boxes__img u-center-landscape">
              <img class="js-box" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/700/" alt="">
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxes__title">Jobbörse</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <div class="boxes__content">
            <div class="boxes__img u-center-landscape">
              <img class="js-box" src="http://lorempixel.com/650/600/" alt="">
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxes__title">Ferienjob</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <div class="boxes__content">
            <div class="boxes__img u-center-landscape">
              <img class="js-box" src="http://lorempixel.com/700/400/" alt="">
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxes__title">Marktplatz</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <div class="boxes__content">
            <div class="boxes__img u-center-landscape">
              <img class="js-box" src="http://lorempixel.com/700/1200/" alt="">
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxes__title">Veranstaltungen</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <div class="boxes__content">
            <div class="boxes__img u-center-landscape">
              <img class="js-box" src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600" alt="">
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxes__title">Gruppen</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <div class="boxes__content">
            <div class="boxes__img u-center-landscape">
              <img class="js-box" src="http://lorempixel.com/1400/1920/" alt="">
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxes__title">Benachrichtigungen</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <div class="boxes__content">
            <div class="boxes__img u-center-landscape">
              <img class="js-box" src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/500/" alt="">
            </div>
            <figcaption>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxes__title">Mein Nachbarn</a>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </section> <!-- end boxes -->
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how much control you have over your HTML, but have you considered using background images instead of `<img>` tags? Then you have enough control in CSS to crop the images without needing any JavaScript. Example:

```css
.boxes__img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes__img" style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/350x150');">
</div>
<div class="boxes__img" style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/150x200');">
</div>
<div class="boxes__img" style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/300x300');">
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Per your request in the comments, here's another technique. Still with only CSS, but with `<img>` elements instead of background images.

```css
.boxes__img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px; 

  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.boxes__img img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 300%;
  max-height: 300%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes__img">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div class="boxes__img">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/150x200" />
</div>
<div class="boxes__img">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/1920x1200" />
</div>
```

Comment: I remember trying to do that and the backend developers said a clear no .What would be the disadvantages using a background image inline?

Comment: From the standpoint of a backend developer, I can't think of any disadvantage. The only arguments to be made are regarding accessibility (`<img>` elements have alt text) and SEO for the same reason.

Comment: @Adrian.I Unless you make pages that - at some point - might be printed I see no valid reason against using background images for this. Also, what Jon said above.

Comment: Ok. Let's say I can't use background images . What are my options ?

Comment: @Adrian.I Edited my answer with another solution for you.

Comment: I've tried to use this technique before and the problem is that if the image is too big( 1900x1200) and your container is 200x200 ,it will display only a tiny portion of the image .

Comment: @Adrian.I Updated my example again with a 1920x1200 image. I used `max-width` to constrain the image from being too large.

Comment: I guess it's a good compromise if I don't want to use javascript. For production purposes what is the most common way to do this ?Are the images cropped on server side ?Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Comment: Typically in a design-heavy site like this, the images would be cropped/resized locally to the ideal resolution and aspect ratio before uploading. The exception would be a site with dynamic content (user uploaded, etc.) where server-side cropping is not simple, but is the most ideal given it means less bandwidth will be downloaded for the user. But CSS is also acceptable, and in terms of CSS solutions, `background-size` is the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use predefined aspect ratios.

#### Mixin

```
@mixin aspect-ratio($width, $height) {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    &:after {
        // Use padding to replace height 
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: ($height / $width) * 100%;
    }
}
```

#### CSS

```
.avatar {
    @include aspect-ratio(1, 1); // alternatively use something like 16,9 or 4,3
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="avatar" style="background-image: url(image.jpg);"></div>
```

#### Live Example

http://codepen.io/jonnyme/pen/WoJVZy

Comment: OP explained that he can't use `background-image` for this task in a comment on the other answer.

Comment: Hm, maybe `object-fit` then? [Doesn't have the greatest browser support though](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).

Comment: I came up with a solution not using `background-image` or `object-fit` in my answer.

Comment: Not helpful to my problem but thanks for taking your time. Can you explain the padding-top trick ?